# Whats the Mathematica command for the skew harmonic number?

Tags: special-functions, number-theory

What's the Mathematica code for the skew harmonic number:
$$\overline{H}_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}.$$

Wolfram expresses this number as
$$\ln(2)-(-1)^n \text{LerchPhi}(-1,1,n+1).$$

I am wondering if there is a **shorter** command that Mathematica can understand.

Comment: Is `Sum[(-1)^(k-1)/k,{k,n}]` satisfactory?

Comment: @Adam thank you but this is just the sum representation.  I'm looking for a simple code.

Comment: H[n_]:=Sum[(-1)^(k-1)/k,{k,n}]  --or--  H[n_] := (Log[
    2] - (-1)^n LerchPhi[-1, 1, n + 1]) ?

Comment: `SeriesCoefficient[Log[x + 1]/(1 - x), {x, 0, n}]`...

Comment: It's not clear why you don't find the expression in terms of the Lerch transcendent satisfactory.

Comment: @J. M. I have no problem with lerch expression I'm asking if there is a shorter expression.

Answer (score 3):

What about

```
Log[2] + (-1)^n*(1/2)*(PolyGamma[1/2 + n/2] - PolyGamma[1 + n/2])
```

or

```
Log[2] + (-1)^n*(1/2)*(HarmonicNumber[-(1/2) + n/2] - HarmonicNumber[n/2])
```

?

Comment: Thank you for the efforts +1

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)" *)

f[n_] = Sum[(-1)^(k - 1)/k, {k, n}] /. (-1)^(n + 1) :> -(-1)^n

(* (-1)^(1 + n) LerchPhi[-1, 1, 1 + n] + Log[2] *)
```

For large `n` this converges to `Log[2]`

```
Limit[f[n], n -> Infinity]

(* Log[2] *)
```

The real part of `f` is

```
f2[n_] = Assuming[Element[n, Reals],
  Re[f[n]] // ComplexExpand // FullSimplify]

(* -Cos[n π] LerchPhi[-1, 1, 1 + n] + Log[2] *)
```

`f2` is equal to `f` for integer arguments:

```
Assuming[Element[n, Integers], f[n] == f2[n] // Simplify]

(* True *)
```

Graphically,

```
Show[
 Plot[f2[n], {n, 0, 25},
  PlotRange -> All,
  GridLines -> {None, {Log[2]}},
  GridLinesStyle ->
   Directive[Gray, AbsoluteThickness[1], Dashed]],
 DiscretePlot[f[n], {n, 0, 25},
  PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][2]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I'm wondering if there is a shorter expression.  +1 though.

Comment: I'll only note that `(-1)^(1 + n) LerchPhi[-1, 1, 1 + n] + Log[2] // FunctionExpand` does nothing, but `(-1)^(1 + n) HurwitzLerchPhi[-1, 1, 1 + n] + Log[2] // FunctionExpand` can be simplified into the expressions in Andreas's answer.