# How to approximate the harmonic sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{{4n\choose 2n}\overline{H}_{2n}}{n 2^{4n}} ?$

Tags: numerics, special-functions, summation, approximation

How to approximate $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{{4n\choose 2n}\overline{H}_{2n}}{n 2^{4n}} ?$$
Where $\overline{H}_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}$  is the skew harmonic number.
The mathematica command for $\overline{H}_{2n}$ is $\log[2]-\text{LerchPhi}[-1,1,2n+1]$.

I tried [Michael E2' command](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/240813/67714):

```
 major = Normal@Series[(Log[2] - LerchPhi[-1, 1, 2 n + 1]) Binomial[4 n, 
   2 n]/(n 2^(4 n)), {n, Infinity, 12}];
 majorsum = Sum[major, {n, Infinity}];
 majorsum + 
 NSum[(Log[2] - LerchPhi[-1, 1, 2 n + 1]) Binomial[4 n, 
  2 n]/(n 2^(4 n)) - major, {n, 1, Infinity}, NSumTerms -> 20, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 20, Method -> "WynnEpsilon"]
```

but it gave a result in terms of $n$ :
[image]

which something unusual to see. Is there any other command or maybe we can do little changes to Michael E2's solution?

Thank you,

Comment: How about a simple-minded approach `N[Sum[Binomial[4 n, 2 n]*(Log[2] - LerchPhi[-1, 1, 2 n + 1])/n/
    2^(4 n), {n, 1, 2000}], 15]` which results in `0.584900923610039`? I leave an estimate of the rest on your own (or ask it in MSE).

Comment: `N[Binomial[4 n, 2 n]*(Log[2] - LerchPhi[-1, 1, 2 n + 1])/n/2^(4 n) /. 
  n -> 2000, 15]` equals `3.09099743792782*10^-6`.

Comment: Making use of [that](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240578/whats-the-mathematica-command-for-the-skew-harmonic-number) , `N[Sum[Normal[
   Series[Binomial[4 n, 
      2 n]*(Log[
          2] + (-1)^
           n*(1/2)*(HarmonicNumber[-(1/2) + n/2] - 
            HarmonicNumber[n/2]))/n/2^(4 n), {n, Infinity, 10}]], {n, 
   2001, Infinity}], 15]` results in `0.0123649321640052`.

Comment: It should be `Log[2] - (-1)^n*LerchPhi[-1, 1, 1 + n]` instead of `Log[2] - LerchPhi[-1, 1, 1 + n]` in your question.

Comment: @user64494 note that $(-1)^{2n}=1$.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a different representation of the skew harmonic numbers in terms of harmonic numbers:
$$
\bar{H}_n=\frac{1}{2} (-1)^n \left(H_{\frac{n-1}{2}}-H_{\frac{n}{2}}\right)+\log (2)
$$
This expression can be expanded around infinity

```
f[n_] := HarmonicNumber[(n - 1)/2] - HarmonicNumber[n/2]
Series[f[n], {n, Infinity, 6}]
```

$$-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2 n^2}-\frac{1}{4 n^4}+\frac{1}{2 n^6}+O\left({n}^{-7}\right)$$

and summed up

```
Sum[Binomial[4 n, 2 n]/(n 2^(4 n)) (Log[2] + (-1)^n 
    (-(1/(2 n)) + 1/(4 n^2) - 1/(8 n^4) + 1/(4 n^6))), 
    {n, Infinity}]
(*3/64 (4 HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 1, 5/4, 7/4}, {3/2, 2, 2, 2}, -1]
-2 HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 1, 1, 5/4, 7/4}, {3/2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, -1] 
+ HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5/4, 7/4}, {3/2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, -1]
-2 HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5/4, 7/4}, {3/2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, -1] 
+8 HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 5/4, 7/4}, {3/2, 2, 2}, 1] Log[2])*)
```

Comment: The result of `Series` is not a good approximation for `f[n]` if `n` is small. Your calculation is not correct:`N[3/64 (4 HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 1, 5/4, 7/4}, {3/2, 2, 2, 
       2}, -1] - 
    2 HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 1, 1, 5/4, 7/4}, {3/2, 2, 2, 2, 
       2}, -1] + 
    HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5/4, 7/4}, {3/2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
      2, 2}, -1] - 
    2 HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5/4, 7/4}, {3/2, 2, 
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, -1] + 
    8 HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 5/4, 7/4}, {3/2, 2, 2}, 1] Log[2])]` is `0.72777`.See my comments to the question.

Comment: I did my answer, having collected my comments. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: I wonder the upvoter: the answer is wrong as explained in my comments.

Comment: @user64494 I voted for the different representation of the skew harmonic number.

Comment: @ChipHurst: That was noticed in my comment to the question before the yarchik's answer.

Comment: @user64494 My answer is incomplete, but not wrong. I demonstrated how the crucial step can be taken. But it is up to the OP to further develop the method.

Comment: Right, the customary approach is to sum finitely many terms, use an approximation for the rest, and try to bound the error of that approximation. A series expansion at infinity is a fine way to get such an approximation. (Why this might be seen as controversial is a mystery. It's a classical method.)

Comment: @yarchik: Let us call things by their proper names: your answer is wrong. You say nothing about any "crucial step" in your answer and you don't derive your answer to a number.

Comment: the question involves $\overline{H}_{2n}$ not $\overline{H}_{n}$.

Answer (score 2):

We can use [Michael E2's method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/240813/4346) with a different representation for the skew Harmonic number:

```
f[n_] = (Log[2] + (-1)^n/2 (HarmonicNumber[(n - 1)/2] - HarmonicNumber[n/2])) Binomial[4n, 2n]/(n*2^(4n));

major = Normal@Series[f[n], {n, Infinity, 12}];
majorsum = Sum[major, {n, Infinity}];
approxtail = N[Sum[f[n] - major, {n, 1, 500}], 30];

majorsum + approxtail
```

> ```
> 0.79573336271051611600770246918
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the efforts (+1)

Answer (score 1):

First, we directly calculate the sum of the first 2000 terms:

```
N[Sum[Binomial[4 n, 2 n]*(Log[2] - LerchPhi[-1, 1, 2 n + 1])/n/     2^(4 n), {n, 1, 2000}], 15]
```

> `0.584900923610039`

Second, making use of [that answer by Andreas](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240578/whats-the-mathematica-command-for-the-skew-harmonic-number),

```
N[Sum[Normal[Series[Binomial[4 n,2 n]*(Log[2] + (-1)^n*(1/2)*(HarmonicNumber[-(1/2) + n/2] - 
HarmonicNumber[n/2]))/n/2^(4 n), {n, Infinity, 10}]], {n,2001, Infinity}], 15]
```

> `0.0123649321640052`

Finally, the sum under consideration approximately equals `0.0123649321640052 + 0.584900923610039`.

Addition. There is a substantial difference between

```
N[Sum[Binomial[4 n, 2 n]*(Log[2] - LerchPhi[-1, 1, 2 n + 1])/n/
2^(4 n), {n, 1, 2000}], 15]
```

> `0.584900923610039`

and

```
N[Sum[Binomial[4 n, 
2 n]*(Log[
    2] + (-1)^
     n*(1/2)*(HarmonicNumber[-(1/2) + n/2] - 
      HarmonicNumber[n/2]))/n/2^(4 n), {n, 1, 2000}], 15]
```

> `0.783368430546511`

The OP writes an incorrect formula  `Log[2] - LerchPhi[-1, 1, 1 + n]` instead of  the correct one `Log[2] - (-1)^n*LerchPhi[-1, 1, 1 + n]` in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts (+1)